# get the size of all columns of a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have used sql query to find the size of column of a table in mysql.This code works for find the size for one column. But i want to get size of all columns of a table in mysql.

```
$sql="SELECT column_name,  character_maximum_length FROM   information_schema.columns 
     WHERE  table_name = 'user' AND column_name = 'Country'";
```

if i have tried this code but it did not work:-

```
<?php

    $sql="SELECT CONCAT(CHARACTER_LENGTH(col1,col2)) FROM tableName 
             WHERE col1 = 'Country' , col2 = 'email'  AND tableName='user'";
    $r= mysql_query($sql);
    $v=mysql_fetch_row($r);
    echo $v[0];
    echo $v[1]; 
?>
```

Comment: select concat query is not work.it cause error

Comment: So, you want one number, which is the SUM of all column lengths for a given table?

Comment: I want all column length of a table for example:- first_name column have 100 and last_name column lenght is 200 like this.

Answer (score 3):

`information_schema.columns` is a table. You need to query it with valid sql queries. Here's an example.

```
 SELECT SUM(character_maximum_length) length,
        table_name
   FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_name='user'
    AND table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND column_name IN ('Country', 'email')
  GROUP BY table_name
```

Notice that you have to filter by schema_name (database name) when you fetch information from `information_schema` tables. Notice also that sizes of columns work differently for numeric and date columns.

Don't rely on this data without experimenting pretty carefully with the results you get from various tables.

And, trying to update these information_schema tables can do bad things to your MySQL server. Don't ask how I know that. :-)

Comment: hello sir, i have tried your code $sql="SELECT SUM(character_maximum_length) length,
        table_name
   FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE table_name='user'
    AND schema_name='send'
    AND column_name IN ('Country', 'email')
  GROUP BY table_name";
 $r= mysql_query($sql);
  $v=mysql_fetch_row($r);
  echo $v[0];
 echo $v[1]; but it gives error :- Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource on line  line   $v=mysql_fetch_row($r);

Comment: **Pro tip #1**: Don't expect code samples you get from the intertoobz, including this web site, to be fully debugged.   **Pro tip #2** Use a database client, like phpMyAdmin, to debug SQL queries before building them into php or other programs.  **Pro tip #3** Check for errors in your php programs. **Pro tip #4** Stop using the `mysql_` interface to access your server from php. It has been deprecated for years.

Comment: But i want to use this sql query in php .the code you provide did not work.